# Update Trigger using Where conditional and old. data

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this homework to do and im into a problem creating triggers,
i have to make an update trigger so i have this table

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  |  x   |
+----+------+
| 2  |  y   |
+----+------+
| 3  |  z   |
+----+------+
```

so, the trigger i was thinking to do is this one

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE TRIGGER updateID AFTER DELETE 
ON personalData FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE personalData
SET id = id - 1
WHERE id > old.id;
END ||
DELIMITER ;
```

the idea is if some user is deleted the id would be updated, as an expample

if x is deleted the table would be

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  |  y   |
+----+------+
| 2  |  z   |
+----+------+
```

when i try to create the trigger the following error shows:

> Error Code: 2014. Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

I was searching for info, but i cant see whats wrong

Comment: It is not possible to do an update on the same table as the trigger. (would be recursive) ... Here's the [mysql info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-triggers.html#faq-mysql-can-triggers-tables): `A trigger can access both old and new data in its own table. A trigger can also affect other tables, but it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.`

Comment: thanks for the help, it was clarifying

Comment: I _think_ it would have the same trouble, but I'd have to check. To me, it _seems_ odd to subtract 1 from an ID ... what if the new ID value (after subtract) already exists? Are there more details about what is trying to be achieved here?

Comment: the principal idea its to update the id's so there is no gap in the order of them.. 1 , 2, 3 <-- delete 2, so you have 1 and 3 and updating the ids you would have 1 and 2 (2 is the befores 3)

Comment: Is the `id` an auto increment field? ... if so, there will still be gaps because that will not change the table-level counter.

Comment: no,isnt incremental

Comment: i was thinking last night, if i create a temporary table with a update triger on it, this would avoid the delete-write problem?is this posible?, the idea is when this temporary table updates catching the old.id this would trigger an update to the personalData table

Comment: Is `id` a primary key?

Comment: yes, i have reserch a lot more on internet and i fiand its not recomended to update pk's because i would have to update all references in the db and can lead to a lots of problems. i will think a easier update trigger for the homework, but i have to say thanks for all Paul, u r the best.

Comment: I don't know that I've helped too much. Maybe the point of the exercise is to discover that is not possible with a trigger? ... I also did a quick check from a stored procedure aspect, and it is the same recursive issue.  Your idea with the temporary table _may_ be possible, but seems rough: how to keep the data between the two tables aligned to maintain the handling.